# Splitting a Java 2D array (4x4) into smaller ones (2x2) and joining them again

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This source code splits a 4x4 array into an array of 2x2...
How can I restore the value of the 2x2 array into a 4x4 array?

```
public class testmatriks {
    private static Random generator = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] mainArray = new double[4][4];
        double[][] subArray = new double[2][2];
        double[][] rubArray = new double[4][4];
        int value;
        for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mainArray[0].length; j++) {
                value = generator.nextInt(255);
                mainArray[i][j] = value;
                System.out.print(mainArray[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("pecah ke piksel 2x2 piksel");

        for (int row = 0; row < (mainArray.length); row += 2) {
            for (int column = 0; column < mainArray[0].length; column += 2) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
                        subArray[k][l] = mainArray[row + k][column + l] * 2;
                        System.out.print(subArray[k][l] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This picture illustrates what I want]

This picture illustrates what I want.

Comment: So you have a 4x4 array, which you split into a 2x2, (you lose a 1/4 of the values then?) and you want to re create into a 4x4?

Comment: It appears that your subarray re-writes itself completely for each chunk of the main array. I see you have row = 0, column = 0, and then you go through every part (k, l) of the subArray and then overwrite the entire sub array with that 1/4 of the main array.
The second iteration of the main array (where row = 0 and column = 2) you will again, write the entire thing into the subArray, destroying the values previously held

Comment: In short, you will need 4 subarrays (or some smart way to combine 4 unique numbers into 1 so they can be put back again) to be able to store that data and then later retrieve it. In the second case, there are tricks you could follow to fit multiple numbers from 0 to 255 into a 'double' datatype.

Comment: sourcecode above is just an example .. !! I actually apply it to the needs of the DCT method ... !!! DCT works by breaking down the overall array into blocks of size 8x8. after the 8x8 sized blocks and inverse transformation. after the phase matrix array is returned to the actual size of the array, in this case does not form a 8x8 again .. !!! please help

Answer (score 3):

This is what you initially have in the 4x4 array:

[a<sub>1</sub>| b<sub>1</sub>| c<sub>1</sub> | d<sub>1</sub>]
[a<sub>2</sub>| b<sub>2</sub>| c<sub>2</sub> | d<sub>2</sub>]
[a<sub>3</sub>| b<sub>3</sub>| c<sub>3</sub> | d<sub>3</sub>]
[a<sub>4</sub>| b<sub>4</sub>| c<sub>4</sub> | d<sub>4</sub>]

This is what will be in the 2x2 array you created:

[2 * c<sub>3</sub>| 2 * d<sub>3</sub>]
[2 * c<sub>4</sub>| 2 * d<sub>4</sub>]

When you say to "restore", it is not clear where to place the values in this 4x4 array, so I will just go with the places in the 4x4 used to create the 2x2:

The code:

```
for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
        mainArray[r + 2][c + 2] = subArray[r][c];
    }
}
```

This should be the content after the code runs:

[a<sub>1</sub>| b<sub>1</sub>|    c<sub>1</sub>     |    d<sub>1</sub>     ]
[a<sub>2</sub>| b<sub>2</sub>|    c<sub>2</sub>     |    d<sub>2</sub>     ]
[a<sub>3</sub>| b<sub>3</sub>| c<sub>3</sub> + c<sub>3</sub>| d<sub>3</sub> + d<sub>3</sub>]
[a<sub>4</sub>| b<sub>4</sub>| c<sub>4</sub> + c<sub>4</sub>| d<sub>4</sub> + d<sub>4</sub>]

---

For splitting the array into smaller chunks, here is what I came up with:

```
/**
* @param larger the larger array to be split into sub arrays of size chunksize
* @param chunksize the size of each sub array
* @precond chunksize > 0 && larger != null
* @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, NullPointerException
*/
public static List<double[][]> chunks(double [][]larger, int chunksize) throws 
    ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, NullPointerException  {
    if (chunksize <= 0)
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Chunks must be atleast 1x1");
    int size = larger.length / chunksize * (larger[0].length / chunksize);
    List<double[][]> subArrays = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
        double[][] sub = new double[chunksize][chunksize];
        int startx = (chunksize * (c / chunksize)) % larger.length;
        int starty = (chunksize * c) % larger[0].length;

        if (starty + chunksize > larger[0].length) {
            starty = 0;
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < chunksize; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < chunksize; col++) {
                sub[row][col] = larger[startx + row][col + starty];
            }
        }
        subArrays.add(sub);
    }

    return subArrays;
}
```

<s>I haven't tested it yet, but you can easily test it with the code you already have.</s>

**Sample usage:**
http://ideone.com/D5Tdgs

Comment: sourcecode above is just an example .. !! I actually apply it to the needs of the DCT method ... !!! DCT works by breaking down the overall array into blocks of size 8x8. after the 8x8 sized blocks and inverse transformation. after the phase matrix array is returned to the actual size of the array, in this case does not form a 8x8 again .. !!! please help

Comment: Well if that is what you are looking to do, then state the problem in a new question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and I'm sure some someone will be able to take a look and correct you on where you have gone wrong

Comment: sorry I do not understand,, advised I just joined this groub

Comment: why if subarray [0] [0] who performed the numbers in the array c3 ...? why do not the numbers that appear in the array a1 ...?

Comment: Your initial question has changed. This is because you are now asking about DCT which is very different question from what the post you have started is about. So my advice is to start a new post, with the title being DCT and give an example code of what your problem is and then some will help you with that

Comment: This has to do with the way you have made your for-loop, you are re-writing the values in the subarray a lot. So only the values written in the last iteration of the first 2 loops will be kept in the array

Comment: is there another way to break the 4x4 array into several blocks of 2x2 ...? so when displayed subarray [0] [0] who performed the value of [a1] ..!

Comment: @JamsirCrown Ok I just posted something, take a look

Comment: ok.i wait your post...!! you have a facebook account or gmail or social media ..? so I can chat with you, once asked about my methods this

Comment: source code methods already exist and could walk but constrained in the array will be in the execution of the array is split into 2x2 4x4 thoroughly and then executed and the results are returned to 4x4?